# jQuery/JavaScript looping over json data results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form where a user can select an item from a mult-select select box (A).  If the item is not listed, the user can add it from another input text box (B).  The value entered in (B) will perform an ajax call which will save the item to the database.  After saving the item, a json object is created which then needs to populate (A) with the updated list.  I have all of this working with the optionss.  I now need to include if the save process passed or failed.  If the process passed, then I need to include the options but if it failed, I just need the failed status.  Here is what I came up with:

```
{
    "process": [{
        "status":"pass" ,
        "message":"The Contributors list has been refreshed to contain the entry you just saved." }
    ],
    "newoptions": [
        {"optionValue":"Item 1" , "optionDisplay":"Item 1"},
        {"optionValue":"Item 2" , "optionDisplay":"Item 2" },
        {"optionValue":"Item 3" , "optionDisplay":"Item 3" }
    ]    
}
```

and this is what I'm using in my .ajax routine:

```
success: function(j){
    if (j.process.status == 'pass'){
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.newoptions.length; i++) 
            {
                options += '<option value="' + j.newoptions[i].optionValue + '">' + j.newoptions[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
            }
        $('#misc_userID').val('');  // reset value back to null 
        $("#misc_userID").effect("transfer", { to: $("#group_misc_available") }, 500);  //visual showing item added to select
        $('#group_misc_available').html(options);
    }
    else if (j.status == 'fail'){
        alert(j.process.message);   
    }
}
```

I'm not getting an error but it isn't processing j.process.status either so the select list (A) isn't being refreshed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `array` of `process` so need to access it with `index`

```
if (j.process.status == 'pass'){
```

Would be

```
if (j.process[0].status == 'pass'){
```

Comment: I thought it would need the [] but didn't know where to put it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are not accessing your json data properly. Try this

```
if (j.process[0].status == 'pass'){
```

Comment: +1 Honorable mention - the other one was just answered first by mere seconds.